# Null check operator used on a null value, can anyone help me?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have finish my flutter apps and it works just fine on an emulator when I debug. But when I release appdebug.apk and emulate it online( here is the link to that emulator google extensions https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apkonline-apk-manager-for/lnhnebkkgjmlgomfkkmkoaefbknopmja), it shows this error:
[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP3S7.png)

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:final_translating_test/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:like_button/like_button.dart';
import 'package:tab_indicator_styler/tab_indicator_styler.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class MyFoodPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFoodPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyFoodPageState createState() => _MyFoodPageState();
}

class _MyFoodPageState extends State<MyFoodPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                child: Container(
                  height: 225,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl:
                        "https://team-building-vietnam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Vietnamese-food-2-980x697.jpg",
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 25, 0, 0),
              child: Text("Ẩm Thực",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "iCiel", color: Colors.white, fontSize: 35)),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 75, 0, 0),
              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("AmThuc"),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Manrope",
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 15)),
            ),
          ]),
          Expanded(
            child: DefaultTabController(
              length: 3,
              child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                body: Column(
                  children: [
                    Divider(),
                    TabBar(
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                      labelColor: Color(0xFF55B5FF),
                      unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff5f6368),
                      isScrollable: true,
                      indicator: MaterialIndicator(
                        color: Colors.blue.shade300,
                        paintingStyle: PaintingStyle.fill,
                      ),
                      tabs: <Widget>[
                        Tab(
                          text:
                              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("CaPhe"),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                              .translate("QuanAnBinhDan"),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                              .translate("NhaHang"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          Scrollbar(
                            child: ListView(children: [
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "TraSuaGiay",
                                  "https://tikibook.com/upload/news/012020/tra-sua-giay-1.jpg",
                                  "LocationTraSuaGiay",
                                  103),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "HuongLong",
                                  "https://huonglongcoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/huonglongcoffee-15.jpg",
                                  "LocationHuongLong",
                                  169),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "DuXanh",
                                  "https://i1.wp.com/kenhhomestay.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/quan-cafe-dak-nong-4.jpg",
                                  "LocationDuXanh",
                                  138),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "SuoiHoa",
                                  "https://i2.wp.com/kenhhomestay.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/quan-cafe-dak-nong-3.jpg",
                                  "LocationSuoiHoa",
                                  192),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "BlackAndWhite",
                                  "https://toplist.vn/images/800px/blackwhite-house-coffeeamptea-685321.jpg",
                                  "LocationBlackAndWhite",
                                  98),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "DakLaoCafe",
                                  "https://toplist.vn/images/800px/cafe-daklao-685406.jpg",
                                  "LocationDakLaoCafe",
                                  192),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "HoaSua",
                                  "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPSKX0tp8UWM3_YmiGFE8FLQX_4TbXW4udExZ9F=s1600-w400",
                                  "LocationHoaSua",
                                  108),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "ALaCa",
                                  "https://ntcogroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ntcodecor-thiet-ke-quan-tra-sua-alaca-dakmil-6.jpg",
                                  "LocationALaCa",
                                  125),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "BepNhaKai",
                                  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgq2IdZ-Oxk-GiOdPqngEXWEMaunoKuUfcaA&usqp=CAU",
                                  "LocationBepNhaKai",
                                  309),
                            ]),
                          ),
                          Scrollbar(
                            child: ListView(children: [
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "NemNuongNgocTram",
                                  "https://images.foody.vn/res/g7/62103/s180x180/foody-ngoc-tram-nem-nuong-nha-trang-988-636667402631257693.jpg",
                                  "LocationNemNuongNgocTram",
                                  148),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "BunBoThao",
                                  "https://images.foody.vn/res/g99/987355/s/foody-bun-bo-thao-987355-719-637121746486643649.jpg",
                                  "LocationBunBoThao",
                                  259),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "MaiTy",
                                  "https://images.foody.vn/res/g66/652636/prof/s576x330/foody-mobile-t4-jpg-568-636281937101170710.jpg",
                                  "LocationMaiTy",
                                  175),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "DeThuyCuong",
                                  "https://www.tourdulichbentre.com/images/com_adsmanager/contents/quan-de-th-y-cuong_3818_1.jpg",
                                  "LocationDeThuyCuong",
                                  298),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "DeDuKi",
                                  "https://images.foody.vn/res/g99/987355/prof/s576x330/foody-upload-api-foody-mobile-bun-bo-hue-200110150825.jpg",
                                  "LocationDeDuKi",
                                  152),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "BeNgocAnh",
                                  "https://images.foody.vn/res/g75/748725/prof/s576x330/foody-upload-api-foody-mobile-recipe7034-635642571-180608134200.jpg",
                                  "LocationBeNgocAnh",
                                  188),
                            ]),
                          ),
                          Scrollbar(
                            child: ListView(children: [
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "NhaHangTuanThao",
                                  "https://www.tourdulichbentre.com/images/com_adsmanager/contents/nha-hang-ti-c-cu-i-tu-n-th-o_3815_1.jpg",
                                  "LocationNhaHangTuanThao",
                                  268),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "NhaHangPhuongThuy",
                                  "https://images.foody.vn/res/g73/720472/prof/s576x330/foody-mobile-hmn-jpg.jpg",
                                  "LocationNhaHangPhuongThuy",
                                  402),
                              foodCard(
                                  context,
                                  "NguyenThanh",
                                  "https://images.foody.vn/res/g77/765827/prof/s576x330/foody-upload-api-foody-mobile-16-gif-180803180808.jpg",
                                  "LocationNguyenThanh",
                                  193),
                            ]),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget foodCard(context, name, url, location, likeCount) {
  return Container(
    height: 300,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: url,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 140),
          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate(name),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, fontFamily: "iCiel", fontSize: 30)),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 190),
              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate(location),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: "Manrope",
                      fontSize: 15)),
            ),
            LikeButton(
              onTap: onLikeButtonTapped,
              likeCount: likeCount,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Future<bool> onLikeButtonTapped(bool isLiked) async {
  /// send your request here
  // final bool success= await sendRequest();

  /// if failed, you can do nothing
  // return success? !isLiked:isLiked;

  return isLiked;
}
```

P/s: I wonder why when I use apprelease.apk file, it didn't work properly. So pls explain that to me too. And pls tell me how to make .apk files uses as a real software without using any emulator.

Comment: In simple terms . You use `!` operator on null value. So search wherever you used `!` operator. As far I can see ```AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("AmThuc")

AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("CaPhe"),

AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("QuanAnBinhDan")

AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("NhaHang"),

AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate(name)

AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate(name)

AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate(location)``` these are the possible places.  My guess --Your context is null.

Comment: Hmmm, let me try it

Comment: The method 'translate' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!'). (I tried to remove it but it showed this error)

Comment: @XiXAm There are a lot of great resources explaining null-safety, I suggest you start with them first :) 
https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: I still don't know why it works perfectly with the code but not with the apk files

Comment: Is yoyr release build possibly misconfigured to not have any localizations?

Comment: No, it is configured exactly, I just checked it. But it also shows this error when I run flutter build apk:Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01